# how to get object from wikipedia json

Tags: javascript, json, wikipedia

I m having problem to get `extract` part from wikipedia json. since page id change from every search

```
{
 "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
   "pages": {
  "49728": {
    "pageid": 49728,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "San Francisco",
    "extract": "<p><b>San Francisco</b></p>"
  }
}
}   
}
```

I have tried following code but still it wont provide me with object with page id

```
 let key = Object.keys( resWiki.query.pages);
 //give 49728
 let data = resWiki.query.pages.key;
```

Anyone can please help me?

Comment: what exactly you want to extract

Comment: @brk i want to extract "49728": {
    "pageid": 49728,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "San Francisco",
    "extract": "<p><b>San Francisco</b></p>"
  }

Comment: What happens if you called your [key] like this? resWiki.query.pages[key]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want it like this.

**Example**

```js
let x = {
 "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
   "pages": {
  "49728": {
    "pageid": 49728,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "San Francisco",
    "extract": "<p><b>San Francisco</b></p>"
  }
}
}   
}
let y = Object.keys(x.query.pages);
console.log(x.query.pages[y].extract)
```

Comment: I dont understand what is happening, I m coming from Java background when you have object inside object how can you get Object by index  pages[y]

Comment: @B'bekShakya javascript objects are different I think. So the above method will do if your key is dynamic. An object in javascript is like an associative array in php where you can reference the index using it's key.

Comment: Thanks for knowledge sir

Comment: @B'bekShakya not a problem, welcome to the world of javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this. This will return the entire `pages` object

```
var key = x.query.pages[Object.keys(x.query.pages)]
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jcx412o0/7/)